# How can I get an campaign's delivery status with Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get

`status`

```
enum {ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, ARCHIVED}
```

and `effective_status`

```
enum {ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, ARCHIVED}
```

as [FB marketing doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group#Reading) said

But when I went to `fb BM backend`, I found the campaign's status was `Not Delivering` as my api-requeses result was `ACTIVE`.

```
{
  "name": "0522_xxxxxx",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "effective_status": "ACTIVE",
  "adsets": {
    "data": [
      {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "effective_status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ads": {
    "data": [
      {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "effective_status": "ACTIVE"

      },
      {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "effective_status": "ACTIVE"
      }]
  }
}
```

In `BM` side, the campaign's  delivery status is in range

```
enum {Active, inactive, Scheduled, Not Delivering, Completed, Not Approved, In Review, In Draft, Delete}
```

Now I'm confusing how to get the delivery status of a campaign.

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Comment: try checking the field `issues_info`

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for your replying, tried but got nothing

Comment: did you solve this issue?